# Server NIC: Difference between IntelPro MT and PT

Tags: networking, iscsi, nic

What's the difference between IntelPro MT and IntelPro PT server adapter cards? Would one of them be better for iSCSI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MT's are PCI-X, the PT's are PCI-e.

Neither offer any hardware iSCSI offload capabilities, so the faster PCI-e card would be the better of the two, though really you should be choosing these on the slot type first and foremost anyway.

If you want iSCSI offload I'd go for one of their I340 server adapters.

Comment: Great thanks. Is iSCSI offload important for target and initiator, or just target?

Comment: Hardware iSCSI offload partially assembles packets on the NIC rather than in CPU, increasing throughput and reducing CPU load on the initiating server - if you have to use iSCSI I highly recommend it.